# Problems getting the record to delete with PHP and access DB

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I have a table with a delete action, but when I go to click it and get prompted to delete the item. It gives me an error. This is connecting to Access database.

Here is the code for the table

```
<table class="table-bordered ">
      <tr>
       <th width="91"> <div align="center">ID </div></th>
        <th width="91"> <div align="center">VendorID </div></th>
        <th width="98"> <div align="center">ItemNumber </div></th>
         <th width="98"> <div align="center">ItemDescription </div></th>
          <th width="98"> <div align="center">UnitDisplay </div></th>
           <th width="98"> <div align="center">Cost </div></th>
           <th>Action</th>


      </tr>
    <?php
    for($i=$Page_Start;$i<=$Page_End;$i++)
    {
        $objResult = odbc_fetch_array($objExec,$i);
    ?>
      <tr>
      <?php $id = $objResult['ItemID'];?>
        <?php echo  "<td> <a href='update.php?ItemID=$id'>$id</a></td>"?>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo $objResult["VendorID"];?></div></td>
        <td><?php echo $objResult["ItemNumber"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $objResult["ItemDescription"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objResult["UnitDisplay"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objResult["Cost"];?></td>
      <td align="center"><a href="JavaScript:if(confirm('Confirm Delete?')==true){window.location='DeleteRecord.php?ItemID=<?php echo $objResult["ItemID"];?>';}">Delete</a></td>

      </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
```

Here is the code for the deleteRecord.php

```
 <?php
    $objConnect = odbc_connect("SupplyRequest","","") or die("Error Connect to Database");
    $strSQL = "DELETE FROM tbl_Items ";
    $strSQL .="WHERE ItemID = '".$_GET["ItemID"]."' ";
    $objExec = odbc_exec($objConnect, $strSQL);
    if($objExec)
    {
        echo "Record Deleted.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error Delete [".$strSQL."]";
    }
    odbc_close($objConnect);
    ?>
```

Comment: what error you see?

Comment: Error Delete [DELETE FROM tbl_Items WHERE ItemID = '921' ]

Comment: your ItemID is string, is correct?

Comment: no integer its the table ID with primary key. the column is called ItemID it keeps going up as each record is entered right now its on record 921

Comment: maybe there is another way I can right this.

Comment: Your parameter ItemID surround with quotes, so it is sent as a string. Try to remove single quotes from sql query

Comment: I found my error log odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SupplyData\deleteRecord.php on line 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out did it this way.

```
<?php
$objConnect = odbc_connect("SupplyRequest","","") or die("Error Connect to Database");
 $ItemID=$_GET['ItemID'];
 $strSQL="DELETE FROM tbl_Items WHERE ItemID= $ItemID";

$objExec = odbc_exec($objConnect, $strSQL);
if($objExec)
{
    echo "Record Deleted.";
}
else
{
    echo "Error Delete [".$strSQL."]";
}
odbc_close($objConnect);
?>
```